# How to connect Google Cloud Run Container to OpenVPN?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, vpn, google-cloud-run, openvpn

We have a Java web app that is trying to access a FTP location behind a OpenVPN.
The app is deployed using Google Cloud Run Containers on their infrastructure.

I managed to deploy a solution that connects to OpenVPN using Docker in my local env but it needs "privileged" rights which we are unable to provide in GCP Cloud Run env.

Can you please help with this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't run a privileged process in Cloud Run, the sandbox denied that. Same thing if you try GKE Autopilot. It's a security best practice. The solution is either to use CloudVPN or to use a Compute Engine as proxy to your FTP connection.